# Flutter ConcatenatingAudioSource from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart, just-audio

I tried hard to fix this playlist but whenever I want to get data from firebase it shows me this error.

and it doesn't show the audio in the playlist

**

```
Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 3872): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 3872): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

**

And this is my code

```
  late AudioPlayer _player;
  int _addedCount = 0;
  var _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: []);
  @override
  PlayList() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('audiosource')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      event.docs
          .map((element) => _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [
                AudioSource.uri(
                  Uri.parse(element['urlmp3'].toString()),
                  tag: AudioMetadata(
                    album: element['ablum'].toString(),
                    title: element['title'].toString(),
                    artwork: element['artwork'].toString(),
                  ),
                )
              ]));
    });
  }
```

I got data as you can see but I can't show it in playlist.

```
{urlmp3: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/muiscapp.appspot.com/o/Glimmer-of-Blooms-I-Cant-Get-You-Out-Of-My-Head.mp3?alt=media&token=8e8ba1fc-d480-4b0e-96ed-c5fe15df8bc2, album: Abdullah, artwork: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/muiscapp.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%202022-04-07%20235942.png?alt=media&token=8cb8a9e6-4476-4270-9bbc-2c935627bdcc, title: Khalid}
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you are not geting the urlmp3
[please refer this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)

Comment: I got the values from firebase but it's not showing in the playlist.